# Урок 4.1 Codebra Мета теги

Tags: html5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Пончики - комбинат пончиков</title>
        <meta property="business:contact_data:country_name" content="Пончикленд">
        <meta name="description" content="продаем пончики уже 28 лет. Предлагаем пончики оптом и в розницу.">
        <meta name="robots" content="nofollow">
        <meta name="twitter:descriptoin" content="Мы продаем пончики уже 28 лет. Предлагаем пончики оптом и в розницу.">
        <meta property="og:description" content="Мы продаем пончики уже 28 лет. Предлагаем пончики оптом и в розницу.">
        <meta itemprop="description" content="Мы продаем пончики уже 28 лет. Предлагаем пончики оптом и в розницу.">


    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>комбинат пончиков - о нас</h1>
        <p>Мы продаем пончики уже 28 лет. Предлагаем пончики оптом и в розницу.</p>

        <p><b>Скидки постоянным клиентам</b></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Вроде написал всё верно, но на проверке показывает что эти 2 задания не выполнены:
Добавьте мета-тег для описания страницы (для поисковиков). Текст для описания возьмите из тега

...

Теперь добавьте тоже самое описание страницы (содержимое

...

) для социальных сетей Twitter, Facebook, Google Plus. Мета-теги для этих социальных сетей есть выше в примерах.

Как с этим жить то теперь?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Пончики - комбинат пончиков</title>
<meta property="business:contact_data:country_name" content="Пончикленд">
<meta name="description" content="Мы продаем пончики уже 28 лет. Предлагаем пончики оптом и в розницу.">
<meta name="robots" content="nofollow">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Мы продаем пончики уже 28 лет. Предлагаем пончики оптом и в розницу.">
<meta itemprop="description" content="Мы продаем пончики уже 28 лет. Предлагаем пончики оптом и в розницу.">
<meta property = "og:description" content = "Мы продаем пончики уже 28 лет. Предлагаем пончики оптом и в розницу.">

</head>
<body itemscope itemtype = "http://schema.org/Product">
<h1 itemprop="name">комбинат пончиков - о нас</h1>
<p itemprop = "description">Мы продаем пончики уже 28 лет. Предлагаем пончики оптом и в розницу.</p>

<p><b>Скидки постоянным клиентам</b></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Я просто ошибся в написании слова `description`.